# MySQL blocked host - Too many connections

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, npm

I'm running a server on Node.js and I'm doing a lot of MySQL queries, about 1-3 queries per second, depends on traffic. Due to this, I made a pool query with the `mysql` npm module, this is how I'm doing it:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: ip,
  multipleStatements: true,
  user: '*********',
  password: '*********',
  database: '*********',
  connectionLimit: 0,
  maxListeners: 0
});
```

And whenever I want to run a query, I run this function:

```
function do_query(query, callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      if(connection) {
        connection.release();
      }
    } else {
      connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
        connection.release();
        return callback(err, results, fields);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

After several hours, or days I'm always getting this error

> Error: ER_HOST_IS_BLOCKED: Host '******' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'.

Why is it getting blocked when I'm setting the connectionLimit to "infinite"? Am I not releasing the connections correctly?

Comment: did you read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blocked-host.html

Comment: @Drew Just did that, let's see if it fixes it. Thank you.

Comment: Let it go for a week and come back and do a self-answer (we would like to know) if it fixes it.

Comment: @Drew Will do that for sure